# porque no se guardan los datos la primera vez que le doy guardar, pero si se guardan la segunda vez?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone

Mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo un formulario cuyos datos se guardan correctamente. El problema es que cuando voy a actualizar (editar) los datos que guarde anteriormente (porque cometí un error al editar o que se yo....), los datos nuevos no se guardan cuando presiono guardar la primera vez. Sin embargo cuando presiono guardar una segunda vez los datos si se guardan. Alguien me da una idea? Dejo el fragmento de código que corresponde a la funcion que se dispara al momento de darle click a "guardar" para actualizar los datos.
Coloqué un alert en la linea 467 para ver el valor que me esta capturando la variable "descuento" (q es la que quiero modificar), y efectivamente me captura el valor correcto apartir de la segunda vez que presiono guardar... en la primera vez me captura el valor viejo (el que tenia antes de modificar)

Comment: Hola Yohanna! Bienvenida a SOes, por favor echale un vistazo al [tour] y a [ask]. En este momento tu pregunta no se entiende del todo, por lo que necesitamos saber qué estás haciendo para lograr resolver tu problema, considera agregar toda la información pertinente a la pregunta haciendo clic en el botón [edit] de tu pregunta, con gusto trataremos de responder !!

Comment: Creo que olvidaste poner el fragmento de código